# Spotify API Curl request to Python Request

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, spotify

I'm currently trying to request an access token through the spotify API and am having trouble because the way the guide requests from the token endpoint is as such:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM...zE=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=MQCbtKe...44KN -d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fauth https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

I'm instead trying to implement this solely in Python and am confused on how I would make this request using the requests library in Python. I've outlined what I think the request should look like:

```
r = requests.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", data = {}, auth = (client_id, client_secret))
```

But I am a little lost, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest to use spotipy library which does it for you. If you want to continue with requests, you maybe want to pass custom `headers` arg with Authorization content.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit this [website](https://curl.trillworks.com/#python).
Your curl command looks like that in python :

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ZjM...zE=',
}

data = {
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'code': 'MQCbtKe...44KN',
  'redirect_uri': 'https://www.your_address.com/auth'
}

response = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', headers=headers, data=data)
```